# $\Bbb{Q}$ is not complete: Carification regarding a proof

Tags: metric-spaces, irrational-numbers

In class today we proved that $\Bbb{Q}$ is not complet,  you used the fact that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{1}{k!}\underset{N\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}e\notin\Bbb{Q}.$$

After that I was perplex to prove that $e\notin\Bbb{Q}$, the method I know used the fact that $e=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}}\frac{1}{k!}$. It seems weird (here) to use this method. So my question is :

> Can I use this method to prove that $e$ is irrational? At least I would like to have a mathematical argument.

*Remark:* Sure, we can always change the sequence and choose for example $u_n=\bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigr)^n$.

Comment: What flaw did you find in the proof ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's not really a flaw, just we used the fact that the sequence tends to $e$ and $e$ is not rational, and I'm not confident in the idea of ​​using that definition again to prove that $e$ is not rational. I hope I am clear..

Comment: No totally. If you don't use some definition, there is nothing you can prove. What is wrong with that one ? A proof is a proof; it extends to any alternative definition proved equivalent.

Comment: On second thoughts I suspect that you see a circular argument like: $e$ is kown not to be rational implies there exists a non rational number. This is not the case. The argument is: there is a number which is the limit of the sum of the inverses of factorial (the sum is convergent), and this number cannot be rational. (If it were, the sum could be expressed as a fraction, with a finite denominator, which is contradictory). It turns out that this number is known as the constant $e$, but this is not relevant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think you solved 'the problem' I need to define $e$ as $=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}}\frac{1}{k!}$ not as a 'result'?

Comment: Yep. You can use other definitions for $e$, and you can follow two paths to show irrationality: a direct proof, exploiting some property in the definition, or an indirect one: first prove that this definition is equivalent to the definition with the sum, and use the above proof. But there are many other provably irrational numbers, such as the Champernowne constant. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant, or simply $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok I will keep this idea in mind. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be much easier for you to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. (I know it is for me.) Anyway there are many rational series that converge to $\sqrt{2}$. My favorite is:
$$\sqrt{2} = 1+ \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\ddots}}} $$